# iPhone 5 screen appears to be using one screw and glue instead of two screws

Tags: hardware, iphone, screen, repair

My iPhone 5 was used when I got it about a year and a half ago, but it appeared to be in perfect condition. However, today I was trying to take the screen off and at that point I noticed it only has one screw on the bottom, and the other screw-hole (the right-side one) is empty. The left side of the screen pops out just fine, but the right side is somehow stuck in there, as you can see in the picture below. If I try to force it out, it starts pulling the "inner shell" thing out with it. The right-side screw-hole is absolutely empty.

[image: My iPhone]

Is it possible that when they were getting the iPhone ready for re-use, they noticed that a screw was missing so they just glued the right side instead? I can't imagine they didn't have extra screws lying around...

Comment: or if the screen was cracked and replaced by DIY :)

Comment: @Buscar웃SD So you're saying the previoue owner got a new screen and glued it in?

Comment: I am not certain of that, but it is a possibility.

Comment: @Buscar웃SD Do you know how I can deal with that?

Comment: Difficult to say, it depends what kind of glue and how much was used. Why do you have to open it ?

Comment: @Buscar웃SD I'm replacing my battery.

Comment: @Buscar웃SD I don't know how to figure out what kind it is, but it seems like there's a lot because it's pretty well glued on there.

Comment: Are you ready for surgery? using a scalpel?, have a steady hand if yes cut it out. If not bring it to repair shop.